# TwoRightBarbutton image on navigation bar One is animated search And second is menu

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I add an animated searchbar button and a menu button on  navigation bar button in iOS?

[image]

Comment: Please show the image search button Tapped then open animated searchbar and hide all the navigation item then camcel button pressed fix position of button like image please shere me

Comment: You can add programmatically or manually .

Comment: I am adding programmetically

Answer (score 0):

Use action methods

```
UIBarButtonItem *menu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuPage)];
UIImage *menuimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[menu setImage:menuimage];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=menu;

UIBarButtonItem *search = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Search" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Searchpage)];
UIImage *searchImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[search setImage:searchImage];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=search;
```

Comment: Actually this right code but i wants two right bar button frame (50,50) like my image see this image and one things search bar animated with fix position of button